# Google Sites API + OAuth2 (on Appengine)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-data-api

I've been trying to make use of the Python Library to access the Google Sites API.

The first step requires a user to authorize our application, they recommend to use OAuth2 and they provide a library that can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/wiki/OAuth2).

At the end of the authorization process you end up with an OAuth2Credentials object.

The problem is, when I try to make requests to the Google Sites API, let's say I do:

```
import gdata.sites.client
client = gdata.sites.client.SitesClient(site=None, domain='mydomain.com')
```

I don't know how to make use of the OAuth2Credentials object.

Comment: have you tried to pass the `Oauth2Credentials.access_token` to the SitesClient constructor?

Comment: Yeah, it didn't work. What I had to do was pass the whole Oauth2Credentials object and monkeypatch it so it had a modify_request method...

Comment: you could write it as an answer for the other experiencing the same problem

Comment: Any chance you would add an answer to this? I'm experiencing the same problem

Comment: Yep I'm getting it too. That "monkeypatch" would sure be handy right about now.

Answer (score 10):

I spent quite a few hours trying to do exactly this and finally found the answer in this blog post:

https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!msg/google-apps-developer-blog/1pGRCivuSUI/3EAIioKp0-wJ

Here is a soup to nuts example of using the oauth2client together with the gdata API to access Google Sites including the 'Monkey Patching':

```
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.tools import run
import gdata.sites.client
import gdata.sites.data

SCOPE = 'https://sites.google.com/feeds/'

# client_secrets.json is downloaded from the API console:
# https://code.google.com/apis/console/#project:<PROJECT_ID>:access
# where <PROJECT_ID> is the ID of your project

flow = flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secrets.json',
                               scope=SCOPE,
                               redirect_uri='http://localhost')

storage = Storage('plus.dat')
credentials = storage.get()

if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    credentials = run(flow, storage)

# 'Monkey Patch' the data in the credentials into a gdata OAuth2Token
# This is based on information in this blog post:
# https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!msg/google-apps-developer-blog/1pGRCivuSUI/3EAIioKp0-wJ

auth2token = gdata.gauth.OAuth2Token(client_id=credentials.client_id,
  client_secret=credentials.client_secret,
  scope=SCOPE,
  access_token=credentials.access_token,
  refresh_token=credentials.refresh_token,
  user_agent='sites-test/1.0')

# Create a gdata client

client = gdata.sites.client.SitesClient(source='sites-test',
                                        site='YOUR.SITE',
                                        domain='YOUR.DOMAIN',
                                        auth_token=auth2token)

# Authorize it

auth2token.authorize(client)

# Call an API e.g. to get the site content feed

feed = client.GetContentFeed()

for entry in feed.entry:
    print '%s [%s]' % (entry.title.text, entry.Kind())
```

Comment: Had the same problem with Google Contact's API, and this resolved it

Answer (score 2):

My app is using .p12 key instead of flow, here is how I made it work after some tinkering:

```
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials
import gdata.sites.client
import gdata.sites.data

scope = 'https://sites.google.com/feeds/'
key_file = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.p12'

with open(key_file) as f:
    key = f.read()

credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
        'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
        key,
        sub='aleh@vaolix.com',
        scope=[scope])

auth2token = gdata.gauth.OAuth2TokenFromCredentials(credentials)
client = gdata.sites.client.SitesClient(source='sites-test',
                                        domain='mydomain.com')
auth2token.authorize(client)

feed = client.GetSiteFeed()

for entry in feed.entry:
    print entry.title.text
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works perfectly for the Server2Server auth flow.

I can't figure why Google's documentation and sample is so horrendous that people have to so struggle so much.

Comment: I guess because they hire only rockstar developers who are above writing documentation.