# How to use OAuth2Credentials with Google API gdata client in python?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, gdata, gdata-api, google-data-api

I've worked out how OAuth2 works (via https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth) and now have an OAuth2Credentials object (let's call the object `credentials`) that I want to use for Google Apps provisioning purposes (the example here is using sites, but could be any of the gdata apis)

If I try:

```
client = gdata.sites.client.SitesClient(site="test-site",domain='my.domain')
client = credentials.authorize(client)
```

I get

```
TypeError: new_request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'http_request'
```

when I try to do anything

If I try

```
client = gdata.sites.client.SitesClient(site="test-site",domain='my.domain', auth_token=credentials)
```

or

```
client = gdata.sites.client.SitesClient(site="test-site",domain='my.domain', auth_token=credentials.access_token)
```

I get an AttributeError that the relevant object (credentials or credentials.access_token)  has no attribute 'modify_request'

Any ideas what I can try?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure about Google's client code, but you could always try (shameless plug) [sanction](https://github.com/demianbrecht/sanction). It's an OAuth 2.0 client I wrote a while ago available on Github and PyPI.

The upsides:

- Being a whopping 55 LOC, it's *tremendously* easy to grok. If something goes wrong, you won't have to ask questions here.. You *should* be able to just understand what's going on ;)
- It has been tested with 8 different providers (including Google)

The downsides:

- Obviously would require a refactor of your current code
- Doesn't assume (and therefore provide) persistence implementations
- Doesn't provide API implementations (you have to have a basic understanding of the OAuth 2.0-exposed API that you're dealing with)

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359725/google-sites-api-oauth2-on-appengine) says you have to monkeypatch the OAuth2Credentials object, before passing it to the `SitesClient(auth_token=credentials)`.  It has an answer showing you how to do the monkey patching

Comment: Saw that, but seems messy, and no supplied code. So I figured I'd see if there were a Proper Way to do it